# prolog how to evaluate math expressions

Tags: prolog

I am studying for an exam and I am having trouble with the prolog section and this question in my book. I would like to create a predicate 'evaluate' that when given any expression sets the value to R. IE: `A=4,B=5, evaluate(((A*B)-2)/3,R)` it evaluates to R = 400. How would I go about creating this?

Comment: Use `is/2` predicate

Answer (score 0):

As @Dmitri Chubarov suggested you could use `is/2`:

```
evaluate(X,R):- R is X.
```

The above simply says R is the **arithmetic result** of X, so `is/2` make all arithmetic operations  and returns the arithmetic result.

Example:

```
?- A=4,B=5, evaluate(((A*B)-2)/3,R).
A = 4,
B = 5,
R = 6.
```